# Method with pointer as argument and autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c

I've found an autorelease pool inside a method passing a pointer as argument.

1.
Is there any relation between the 2 ?

```
- (void)exportXMLToString:(NSMutableString **)aString
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableString *theString = *aString;
```

2.
More in general, why do I want to pass the pointer to a string can't I just pass the string itself and returning it back ?

3.
If I want to override such method, and invoking the superclass method from it, can I just write this ? (and the same string is used ?

```
 - (void)exportXMLToString:(NSMutableString **)aString
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSMutableString *theString = *aString;

            ...

            [super exportXMLToString:aString];
   }
```

thanks

Comment: Please note that `**` is a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the string like this makes it so that any changes to the string that are made to the string inside the method will persist outside the method. It takes XML and stores it in the string you provided.

The autorelease pool just handles all the autorelease statements that take place before that pool is drained. If you are executing a bunch of code that could generate a great deal of autoreleased objects, you can wrap that code in its own autorelease pool instead of waiting on for the next time the default one drains. It is unrelated to how the string is passed into the method.

If you plan to invoke the superclass method from your overridden method, you don't need to add another autorelease pool unless you are doing a bunch of autoreleasing of your own outside the superclass method. It will still create and handle its own autorelease pool as it did before.

Comment: Thanks! one last question: in my code I'm assigning aString to the local theString object. If I invoke the super method after this line, are the changes made to both theString and aString ? In other terms, am i still referring to the same object in memory correct ?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you make calls to the methods provided by NSMutableString, they will affect both, but just assigning values may not have the affect you would expect. An NSString is already a pointer to an NSString object. The value passed in is a pointer to a pointer to an NSString object. The NSString * theString is just a regular pointer to a string and you assign it to point to the same string that the pointer aString points to is pointing to. Sorry, I know that's a lot of pointing. Let me know if it needs more clarification.

Comment: Basically, if you change what aString points to, it will change outside the method as well. 'aString = &theString' would cause whatever string you passed in to the method to point to theString even after you have exited the method.

Comment: OK, just to be sure, how would you change the code above ? (Consider I need to some changes before and after the invocation of the superclass method

Comment: It is hard to say if I do not know what you are trying to achieve with the overridden method.

Comment: I'm just appending strings to theString [theString appendFormat:@" new word"];

Comment: If you are appending anything extra in your overridden method, you should still get the reference like you are doing. My guess is that you would want to append additional stuff after the super method is called since it will be storing stuff into the string. I cannot tell without seeing the implementation, but I would guess that what you pass in to the super method just gets tossed out. You should most likely eliminate the autorelease pool from your overridden method and leave that to the super method. It is hard to tell anything for sure without seeing the full implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is completely wrong:

```
 - (void)exportXMLToString:(NSMutableString **)aString
```

There is *never* a reason to have a method that returns `void` *and* takes a `**` argument.  Instead, it should just return the value directly.

Pass by reference is used very rarely in Objective-C, typically only for `NSError**` parameters, though there are a handful of others.